# GET http://localhost:4000/ 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, web-frontend

Refused to load the image '**http://localhost:4000/favicon.ico**' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'". Note that 'img-src' was not explicitly set, so 'default-src' is used as a fallback.

I have tried to rebuild the server using different port also, but issue persist the same.
Any solution???
"dependencies": {
"express": "^4.17.1",
"socket.io": "^2.3.0"
}

Answer (score 0):

The server appears to be sending a CSP (Content Security Policy) header and as the error message says, it has not set any 'img-src' so it falls back to 'default-src' which is None.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/default-src

If you are expecting the server to provide images, see if you can set the used CSP, how to do this is dependent on which webserver you use, so a little more information is needed to help with that.